# JQuery animate queuing

Tags: jquery, queue, jquery-animate

I'm working on [this website](http://bigballoon.businesscatalyst.com/) and have implemented JQuery's `animate()` for the first time (on the navigation). It's all working fine in the browsers that I have and whatnot, but I've noticed it seems to queue the animations. By this I mean, if you flick your mouse back and forward over the navigation quickly, the items will continue to jump up and down until the queue is empty.

Here's my `animate()` stuff:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Navigation effects
    $("table#cat_752586 td").mouseover(function()
    {
        $(this).animate({
            marginTop: "0px",
            lineHeight: "60px"
        }, 350);
    });

    $("table#cat_752586 td").mouseout(function()
    {
        $(this).animate({
            marginTop: "20px",
            lineHeight: "36px"
        }, 350);
    });
});
```

What's the easiest way to discard this feature from my navigation?

---

Just thought of something: the animation for rolling off still needs to queue after the one for rolling on in cases where you roll over the nav and roll off instantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) before [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
$(this).stop().animate({});
```

There are 2 parameters that `.stop()` takes which you may way to configure depending on if you want the animation to jump to the end and/or clear the queue. Usually a `.stop(true)` will suffice.

**Edit:** There is a combined mouseover/mouseout version which is cleaner.

```
$("table#cat_752586 td").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).stop(true).animate({
        marginTop: "0px",
        lineHeight: "60px"
    }, 350);
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).stop(true).animate({
        marginTop: "20px",
        lineHeight: "36px"
    }, 350);
});
```

Comment: Awesome edit, I keep forgetting you can chain stuff like that, I'll try make more use of it.

Answer (score 4):

Replace:

```
$(this).animate(...)
```

with this:

```
$(this).stop().animate(...)
```

That will stop any running animation before starting a new one, effective flushing the queue.

See [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/stop).

Comment: To meet the requirements of my added note in the question (sorry) do I just implement this on one of the .animate()'s? If so, which one?

Comment: I think you always want `stop()`.   The implication in your added question is that you want the "on" animation to run to completion even if I immediately roll off - I'd have thought you'd want the "off" animation to replace it immediately.  See http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/01/quick-tip-prevent-animation-queue-buildup for an example.

Comment: You're right, after implementing stop() in both I think I'm happy with the result.